# Mouse can't interact with applications

Tags: fedora, gnome3, mouse, wayland

I'm running Fedora 24 `$ uname -a`

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.7.7-200.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 8 00:21:59 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)
```

After some time (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours) my mouse will stop interacting with any application that I am running. It is, however, able to interact with the application menu at the top and so I am able to log out. After logging back in, the mouse will interact with the applications again.

This is pretty annoying! Anyone know how to resolve/debug this issue?

I am using wayland, not X.

Comment: fill a bugreport: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bugs_and_feature_requests#Do_I_need_to_file_a_bug.3F

Comment: Filed - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1389432

Comment: try `xdotool mouseup 1; xdotool mouseup 2; xdotool mouseup 3`, not a solution, but would be interesting to see if that "fixes" it

Comment: @mikejonesey nope that didnt work. Its very frustrating. Any ideas on what could even be the issue? no response from fedora or here!

Comment: Can you see the mouse movements/button presses in `xev`?

Comment: I am using wayland not X i should point out.